# How do you calculate the coordinates a quadratic curve follows?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-programming

I'm a programmer, and terrible at maths. Usually, I try Google or my math-addict co-worker for problems like this, but Google searches show nothing and my co-worker is on vacation for a few weeks. I am working in an HTML5 canvas, explained here:

http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-quadraticcurveto-function.html

Basically, on an X/Y grid, the startpoint is at 75X/200Y, the control point is at 300X/50Y, and the endpoint is at 525X/200Y. What formula can I use to get a number of coordinates along the drawn line?

Edit: The formula created with the help of the selected answer:

```
var curveX = (1 - i) * ((1 - i) * startPoint.x + (i * controlPointX)) + i * (((1 - i) * controlPointX + (i * endPoint.x)));
var curveY = (1 - i) * ((1 - i) * startPoint.y + (i * controlPointY)) + i * (((1 - i) * controlPointY + (i * endPoint.y)));
```

The variable i is a variable from a for loop, that goes from 0.1 to i < 1, increasing by 0.1. You can increase this loop for more coordinates, like using 0.05 instead of 0.1.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves It's really not that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B(t)=(1-t)((1-t)P_0+tP_1)+t((1-t)P_1+tP_2)$$

As [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve) says, $B(t)$ is a point on the curve for all $t\in[0,1]$. $P_0,P_1, P_2$ are the starting point, control point, and end point.

In case you are not familiar with linear algebra or vectors, you can put the x-coordinates of the points into this equation, and then $B(t)$ will be the x-coordinate of a point on the line, for all $t\in[0,1]$. Same for y-coordinate.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that (t) is Time, and goes from 0 to 1?

Comment: @Bas: $t$ can be thought of as "time", sure. $B(0)$ is the starting point and $B(1)$ is the ending point.

Comment: All right, then I now know what to do. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Bas: If you have any other questions, please ask.

Comment: @Bas: And I'd like to hear if what you are trying to do works!

Comment: It's not perfect yet, but I can't tell if it's a bug in my code, or in the formula I'm using. The line I'm drawing using this formula starts far away from the intended starting point. Can you please tell me if my formula is identical to the one in your answer? I think so, but my output disagrees.

Comment: @Bas: Looks like you are diving by $i$ at the end?

Comment: I thought B(t) meant that the answer you get from the formula was equal to B*t. I removed the /i part and it works flawlessly! After work, it's time I download a maths book and start working on basic knowledge. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Bas: Ahh! Sorry. $B(t)$ is notation for the value of the function $B$ at $t$. You, as a programmer, are familiar with this, yes?

Comment: I'm afraid maths is not part of the curriculum I'm currently doing, and up to now I have not really seen a need for knowing any maths either. However, being able to read formulas and translating them to code is a valuable skill. I'll have to invest some time in learning to completely understand the formulas I read!